# Upload file in Azure datalake via api using c#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, file-upload, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to upload files in datalake using an api. I've having some problems, while uploading.

I have tried different examples found online but none solved my case. These are some of examples : https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/cloud-development/uploading-files-azure-data-lake-using-net-app/

https://www.taygan.co/blog/2018/01/02/upload-a-file-to-azure-data-lake-store-using-net

Let me show you how fare I've come with my code :

```
public  IActionResult UploadFileOnAzure( string path, string name, IFormFile file)
    {

        _dlsService.CreateDir(path, name); //this works
        //create file
        _dlsService.CreateFile(path); //this also works so I create a file in azure
    //I would like to know what are my next steps from here. How should I upload the file in azure? 
     Should I convert the file in a stream then write the created file? I'm very confused. 

        return null;
    }

 private AdlsClient _client;

 public async Task<Stream> CreateFile(string path)
    {
        return await _client.CreateFileAsync(path, IfExists.Fail);
    }
```

I would like to know what are my next steps from here. How should I upload the file in azure? Should I convert the file in a stream then write the created file? I'm very confused.

Any help would be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, when we use `CreateFileAsync` method, it will automatically creates any parent directories that don't exist so we do not need to create directories. Besides, it will return Stream then you can the stream to upload file. For example

My code :

```
ServiceClientCredentials cred = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            AdlsClient client = AdlsClient.CreateClient("test089.azuredatalakestore.net", cred);

            string path = "/Test/testFilename.txt";
            using (var stream = client.CreateFile(path, IfExists.Fail))
            {

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"E:\mytest.txt"))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ( (line =sr.ReadLine()) != null) {


                        var textBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line + "\n\r");
                        stream.Write(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);

                    }
                }
              

            }
```

Before I run code
[image]

After I run code
[image]

For more details, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-using-active-directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-net-sdk#create-a-file-and-directory

Comment: @pavel Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: I'm so sorry I never saw your answer. Actually I managed to solve it in another way, but his is also useful. I'll mark it as the correct answer.